# About an arc problem in munkres

Tags: general-topology

In munkres's topology book, an arc is a topological space homeomorphic to an unit interval in R.  The problem 1 in the section 64 asks to show that when X is union of finitely many arcs each pair of which intersect in at most a common end point, X is hausdorff iff each arcs is closed in X.

Well i thought the arcs are closed in X automatically since those are homeomorphic to the unit interval in R. But it seems that this is not the case. Why?

Furthermore it asks to show the 'line with two origins' is an union of arcs but not hausdorff. How is it an union of arcs where each pair intersect in at most a common point? I got no clue. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For instance, the "interval" $[-1, 1]$ on the real line with two origins fulfills everything except that the arcs are closed in $X$ (one arc from $-1$ to and including one of the origins, the other arc from the other origin to and including $1$), and the two origins are not Hausdorffly separated.

Comment: But the pair you have given does not intersect at a point, does it?

Comment: @Mathcho notice that the Munkres exercise says the arcs intersect at "*at most* a common end point."

Comment: Oh my, i missed such an important note... thanks mike.